# Error: indexed name is not a integer

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I got an error when I synthesized my project. I have an error in this line:

```
axi_rdata <= patternCount(axi_awaddr(ADDR_LSB+OPT_MEM_ADDR_BITS downto ADDR_LSB));
```

and I got this error:

> [Synth 8-2234] indexed name is not a integer

I would appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: You need to add declarations for the objects used in this code snippet.

Comment: The basic problem is that you're trying to index `patternCount`, which is presumably some sort of array, by a bitfield taken from `axi_awaddr`. You can only index an array with an integer. If you clarify the object types in the question, I can make an answer.

Comment: @scary_jeff  thanks for answering , this is the type of the `patternCount` : 


`type PatternCount_memory is array (31 to 0) of std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

 signal patternCount : PatternCount_memory; `

Comment: @scary_jeff - You're conflating  index position and value. Consider using an enumeration type as an index range.  See IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.2.2 Enumeration types, 5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete range. *You can only index and array with an integer* is not accurate.

Comment: I hope the answer is OK. It would be best to add the declaration to the question itself, so that others can more easily see what exactly your question involved.

Comment: This question is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please add your declarations to to the question. Comments aren't searchable nor part of the question and answer narrative.

Comment: @user1155120 What I meant was that you can only index an array *using integers* (which would include ranges specified using integers). If only I could edit the comment.

Comment: @user1155120 Can you point to an example regarding the enumeration types? The standard is not public, and I don't really understand what you mean

Comment: @scary_jeff `entity foo is
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is
    type enum_index is (ZERO, ONE, TWO, THREE);
    type array_type is array (enum_index'LEFT to enum_index'RIGHT) of integer;
    signal enum_array: array_type;
begin
    enum_array(ONE) <= 0;
end architecture;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared an array type:

```
type PatternCount_memory is array (31 to 0) of std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
signal patternCount : PatternCount_memory;
```

You would normally access elements in this array like this:

```
a <= patternCount(3);
b <= patternCount(0);
```

As you can see, the array is indexed with an integer. If you have a bitfield:

```
signal bit_field : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := "01010";
```

Then it is an error to index your array directly using this:

```
a <= patternCount(bit_field);  -- Error, indexed name is not an integer
```

You probably want to convert your bitfield, so that it is interpreted as an integer:

```
a <= patternCount(to_integer(unsigned(bit_field)));  -- OK, we have converted our bitfield
```

These conversion functions are available when using the `numeric_std` package.

Comment: thank you so much , it is solved , it was really help full